# Android Error using findViewById

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am new to this android application development. I am trying to find textfield using findViewById Eclipse keep asking me to create a new method for findViewById. Here is my code.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
                          ViewGroup container, Bundle SavedInstanceState) {

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.myFragment, container,false);

//find textarea 
    TextView textArea = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtField_curDateTime);
}
```

Please note i have myFragment.java and myFragment.xml files.

Appreciate your help. 
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myFragment, container,false);

TextView textArea = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtField_curDateTime);

return v;
```

Moreover, define `TextView textArea` outside the `onCreateView` so that its available to other methods too.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
                      ViewGroup container, Bundle SavedInstanceState) {

View vObject = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myFragment, container,false);

   //find textarea 
TextView textArea = (TextView)vObject.findViewById(R.id.txtField_curDateTime);


 return vObject;
}
```